# Add a New Line After a Match is Found Using Matched Pattern in Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

Suppose I have a file with contents like this:

```
[abc]
123
456

[def]
789
012
```

I want to insert a new line each time we find a string within a square bracket (here is [abc], [def]), and the added new line is like this:

```
foo=found_content,
```

Where found_content is the content within the square bracket. So after we run the command the content of the file should look like this:

```
[abc]
foo=abc
123
456

[def]
foo=def
789
012
```

How can we achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Is the `[....]` always on a separate line? What chars can be inside `[...]`? Any? Please add the  code that does not work for you, it will clarify what you are doing and will help us help you better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one-liner should give you a hand:

```
awk -F'[][]' '7;NF==3{print "foo="$2}' file
```

The idea is, set the `[ or ]` as `FS`, for the `[...]` line, add the new line `foo=field2` below it.

Comment: funny! first after posting the answer 10 seconds, I got downvoted, I posted a comment, "downvoter, I don't think you have even read my answer before you downvote", then this comment was removed as well. Great, a powerful downvoter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That really helps! I don't know why someone downvote this.